# Parceable ArrayLists (Android)

Tags: android, object, android-intent

Im trying to pass objects with intents between activities in an Android app. I know that objects must be made parceable or serializable (sorry for my spelling) before they can be passes through intents. However, in my case the objects are in an array list when they are passed through the intent.

Do I have to make the arraylist parceable before I pass it? Or do I simply have to make the objects in the list parceable when I pass it? Iv'e been having a lot of trouble passing theses array lists and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in ArrayList should be parcelable. Here is good example on how to do it.[Android arraylist parcelable](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html)